# What is the best technique for underwater imaging?

Tags: image-processing, reference-request, video-processing, sonar

I am currently researching what the best method to take underwater images/video is. The papers I have read go into several different methods: [Lidar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar), [Synthetic Aperture Sonar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_aperture_sonar) (SAS), optical camera plus light source, etc.

What is the best method/industry standard?

I am guessing the answer to this question is going to be "it depends on the application." So, to narrow the question down a bit, my two applications are

1. **mapping the sea floor** (I suspect SAS is the best for this one)
2. **taking very high resolution pictures of an object close to the system**, like a fish or even millimeter-sized animals if possible.

Obviously, these are very different applications, so different techniques might be better at one than the other, which is fine.

If there are some notable articles and textbooks I could be pointed to that would be very helpful. Ones that are current with today's best practices. Thank you.